# Why changing the access specifier for const data member causes the program to compile

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to understand why is this code block below, compile if i change the access control to public.

```
#include <iostream>
class Test
{
    const int i;
};

int main()
{
    Test a{};
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What are reasons causing to compiled/error in either cases. Detailed explanation would help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it turns `Test a{};` into an aggregate initialization: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Answer (score 1):

All non-static `const` class members must be initialized by the class's constructor. This is fundamental to C++.

A `const` class member, therefore, results in the class's default constructor getting deleted. The class has no default constructor.

However, aggregate initialization is still possible with public `const` class members, they can be aggregate-initialized. So that's allowed. `a{};` is aggregate initialization, with `i` default-initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental behind constant is, the variable cannot be altered later (modified).

So, it is always good practice to initialize when a constant variable declared.

When you change the access specifier to public it compiles by default initialized.
But what is the use of it, as you cannot modify the value.

```
class Test
{
    const int i = 8; //EXAMPLE. This works irrespective of access specifier.
};
```